# Shifting the FFT of a signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to implement a spectral correlation function to plot with the surf function. 
I think I understand the idea of the SCF as described in a paper I read, but I'm having trouble implementing my function in Matlab. I've been following these instructions:

[image: Pseudo-code]

I'm mostly having trouble shifting my pieces of the data properly. Is there an easy way to achieve step 3?

Here's what I tried in my code:

```
function [output] = spectral(x, N)
    % This function does cyclostationary spectral analysis 
    % on a data set and returns some features

    t = length(x); 
    samplesPerFrame = floor(t / N); 

    count = 1; 

    for alpha = -1:0.01:1



        % Split up the samples into frames
        % Have to leave some samples out if unevenly split
        for i = 1:N+1
            frange = ((i - 1) * samplesPerFrame + 1):(i * samplesPerFrame);
            if i == N+1
                break;
            end
            xFrame(i, :) = x(frange);
            ts = [1:length(xFrame(i,:))]; 
            shiftLeft = fft(xFrame(i, :) .* exp(-1 * 2 * pi * 1i * (alpha / 2) .* ts));
            shiftRight = fft(xFrame(i, :).* exp(2 * pi * 1i * (alpha / 2) .* ts)); 

            S(i,:) = (1 / samplesPerFrame) .* shiftLeft .* conj(shiftRight);

        end

        Savg(count, :) = mean(S, 1);
        Ssmooth(count, :) = smooth(Savg(count,:), 'moving'); 
        count = count + 1; 
    end
    output = Ssmooth; 
end
```

Comment: What's problems have you been having? What have you tried so far? We can't know how to help you if you don't give us any details.

Comment: I added some more details. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good actually.

You may also try `circshift(fft(xFrame(i, :)),[1,a])` to achieve `shiftRight`, and `circshift(fft(xFrame(i, :)),[1,-a])` to get `shiftLeft`. Please note here `a` is integer, indicates the elements in `xFrame(i, :)` that you wish to move, and corresponds to `Fs*a` in frequency domain where `Fs` is your sampling rate.

Comment: Do you mean shift the fft of xFrame(i, :) with circshift?

Answer (score 1):

The method of spectral correlation estimation you are attempting is something I refer to as the Time-Smoothing Method of spectral correlation estimation, or the TSM. The code you posted cannot provide the correct answer except in some trivial cases such as alpha = 0. The reason is that you need to adjust the cyclic periodogram for each frame by a complex phase factor to compensate for the fact that each data block is a delayed version of the one preceding it.

If you replace the line

S(i,:) = (1 / samplesPerFrame) .* shiftLeft .* conj(shiftRight);

with the two lines

S(i,:) = (1 / samplesPerFrame) .* shiftLeft .* conj(shiftRight);

S(i, :) = S(i, :) * exp(-1i * 2 * pi * alpha * i * samplesPerFrame);

you'll be able to estimate the SCF. I confirmed this by applying your original code and the modified code to a BPSK signal with bit rate (normalized) of 1/10. In this case, one of your alpha values in the loop over alpha will exactly coincide with the true cycle frequency of 1/10. Only the modified code gives the correct SCF for the bit-rate cycle frequency.

Please see my blog cyclostationary.wordpress.com for more detail and examples. In particular, I have a post on the TSM at 
http://cyclostationary.blog/2015/12/18/csp-estimators-the-time-smoothing-method. (Corrected this link 5/2/17.)